# Add page number in template using phpWord

Tags: php, docx, phpword

I would like to have the number of pages of my document in a template processed by phpWord.

I tried to do it with the following code :

In my template I have "the number of pages is ${total_pages}$

And I tried the following php code :

```
    $pages_text = new TextRun();
    $pages_text->addField('NUMPAGES');
    $processor->setComplexValue('total_pages',$pages_text);
```

Problem is it always prints 1 as a number of page. 
So i have "the number of page is 1" even if my template has 4 pages.

Could you help me with that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [preserveText](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#preserve-texts)? Might be simpler.

```
$footer->addPreserveText('Page {PAGE} of {NUMPAGES}.');
```

You can also use `{SECTIONPAGES}`. You can't add preserve text into a text run, however, so it must be used just like the addText method.

Comment: The problem is that I am using a template, so the only way I have to replace a variable is with a textrun object ...

Comment: @PierreFtn I have the same problem, do we have any solution of this issue?